# Sending oauth token from android causes KeyNotFoundException

Tags: android, wcf, soap, dotnetopenauth

We are currently delevoping an app which uses the DotNetOpenAuth library to secure a wcf SOAP web service via OAuth. The whole thing runs on IIS7. The web service and the DotNetOpenAuth library are running smoothly, at least when running on a PC. Calling the service from an android platform, however, causes a few hickups. Sometimes it'll run just fine, and sometimes it'll cause an exception saying "sequence contains no elements".

Unfortunately I don't have all the details, since I myself don't actually have an android available. However, when reading log files created by my colleagues, a few things stand out.

The Windows Event log indicates that this is a KeyNotFoundException, which happens because the token is recognized (the token, in fact, *is* present in the database so this shouldn't happen- I've checked).

Furthermore, what's really interesting, is that this exception only happens whenever a + or / symbol is present in the oauth_token parameter. I'm kinda leaning towards thinking this is an encoding problem where the two characters are not encoded properly. When checking the Windows Event log, anytime the oauth_token parameter contains a + or /, it is replaced by a space. However I have no idea where this is encoded, why those two characters are replaced with a space and, most importantly right now, how to fix it.

I've also enabled log4net logging, which shows that the oauth_token variable is identitcal to what's in the database. It does, however, show the constructed signature base string to contain the oauth_token, only the / character is replaced with %252F. A few lines lower, however, the oauth_token variable is shown seperately (ie not as part of the base string, but in a summary of variables), and there the / is actually displayed as a /.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

*Logs retrieved from log4net*

```
2012-05-18 13:05:21,588 (GMT+2) [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send UnauthorizedTokenResponse (1.0.1) message.
  2012-05-18 13:05:22,099 (GMT+2) [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.TokenHandlingBindingElement applied to message.
  2012-05-18 13:05:22,100 (GMT+2) [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthHttpMethodBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:22,102 (GMT+2) [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:22,104 (GMT+2) [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:22,109 (GMT+2) [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElementChain did not apply to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:22,113 (GMT+2) [5] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing UnauthorizedTokenResponse (1.0.1) message for <response>: 
    oauth_token: LgelzDbE0hd8Z+HrRQWD63SzNA8=
    oauth_token_secret: eK1sVTQvF6LrHqrtDGXe4LpLunI=
    oauth_callback_confirmed: true

2012-05-18 13:05:22,113 (GMT+2) [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending message: UnauthorizedTokenResponse
2012-05-18 13:05:22,463 (GMT+2) [5] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: https://websrv.hszuyd.nl/serviceprovider/v2/OAuth.ashx?oauth_token=LgelzDbE0hd8Z+HrRQWD63SzNA8=
2012-05-18 13:05:22,996 (GMT+2) [5] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.OAuthServiceProvider - An unhandled exception occurred in ASP.NET processing: DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: A token in the message was not recognized by the service provider. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Unrecognized token ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.DatabaseTokenManager.GetRequestToken(String token) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\DatabaseTokenManager.cs:line 31
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.DatabaseTokenManager.GetRequestToken(String token) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\DatabaseTokenManager.cs:line 35
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.cs:line 80
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.cs:line 100
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.CustomOAuthMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\CustomOAuthTypeProvider.cs:line 24
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Receive(Dictionary`2 fields, MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 713
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthChannel.ReadFromRequestCore(HttpRequestInfo request) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthChannel.cs:line 194
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest(HttpRequestInfo httpRequest) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 422
   at OAuth.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in d:\oauthSiteTest\serviceprovider\v2\OAuth.ashx:line 21
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: A token in the message was not recognized by the service provider. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Unrecognized token ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.DatabaseTokenManager.GetRequestToken(String token) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\DatabaseTokenManager.cs:line 31
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.DatabaseTokenManager.GetRequestToken(String token) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\DatabaseTokenManager.cs:line 35
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.cs:line 80
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.cs:line 100
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.CustomOAuthMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\CustomOAuthTypeProvider.cs:line 24
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Receive(Dictionary`2 fields, MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 713
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthChannel.ReadFromRequestCore(HttpRequestInfo request) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthChannel.cs:line 194
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest(HttpRequestInfo httpRequest) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 422
   at OAuth.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in d:\oauthSiteTest\serviceprovider\v2\OAuth.ashx:line 21
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


2012-05-18 13:05:27,382 (GMT+2) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send UnauthorizedTokenResponse (1.0.1) message.
2012-05-18 13:05:27,430 (GMT+2) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.TokenHandlingBindingElement applied to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:27,430 (GMT+2) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthHttpMethodBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:27,430 (GMT+2) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:27,430 (GMT+2) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:27,430 (GMT+2) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElementChain did not apply to message.
2012-05-18 13:05:27,430 (GMT+2) [6] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing UnauthorizedTokenResponse (1.0.1) message for <response>: 
    oauth_token: tdKwMhsNOyQPTiz+K5th/RZr0F8=
    oauth_token_secret: UtfdLNG0VqrTGinchsNfjbyFBtE=
    oauth_callback_confirmed: true

2012-05-18 13:05:27,430 (GMT+2) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending message: UnauthorizedTokenResponse
2012-05-18 13:05:27,503 (GMT+2) [6] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: https://websrv.hszuyd.nl/serviceprovider/v2/OAuth.ashx?oauth_token=tdKwMhsNOyQPTiz+K5th/RZr0F8=
2012-05-18 13:05:27,512 (GMT+2) [6] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.OAuthServiceProvider - An unhandled exception occurred in ASP.NET processing: DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: A token in the message was not recognized by the service provider. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Unrecognized token ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.DatabaseTokenManager.GetRequestToken(String token) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\DatabaseTokenManager.cs:line 31
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.DatabaseTokenManager.GetRequestToken(String token) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\DatabaseTokenManager.cs:line 35
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.cs:line 80
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.cs:line 100
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.CustomOAuthMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\CustomOAuthTypeProvider.cs:line 24
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Receive(Dictionary`2 fields, MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 713
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthChannel.ReadFromRequestCore(HttpRequestInfo request) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthChannel.cs:line 194
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest(HttpRequestInfo httpRequest) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 422
   at OAuth.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in d:\oauthSiteTest\serviceprovider\v2\OAuth.ashx:line 21
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: A token in the message was not recognized by the service provider. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Unrecognized token ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.DatabaseTokenManager.GetRequestToken(String token) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\DatabaseTokenManager.cs:line 31
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.DatabaseTokenManager.GetRequestToken(String token) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\DatabaseTokenManager.cs:line 35
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.cs:line 80
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthServiceProviderMessageFactory.cs:line 100
   at OAuthServiceProvider.Code.CustomOAuthMessageFactory.GetNewRequestMessage(MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient, IDictionary`2 fields) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\sp\Code\CustomOAuthTypeProvider.cs:line 24
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Receive(Dictionary`2 fields, MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 713
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthChannel.ReadFromRequestCore(HttpRequestInfo request) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ChannelElements\OAuthChannel.cs:line 194
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest(HttpRequestInfo httpRequest) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 422
   at OAuth.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in d:\oauthSiteTest\serviceprovider\v2\OAuth.ashx:line 21
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2012-05-18 13:05:30,486 (GMT+2) [5] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: https://websrv.hszuyd.nl/serviceprovider/v2/OAuth.ashx
2012-05-18 13:05:30,487 (GMT+2) [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Incoming request received: RequestScopedTokenMessage
2012-05-18 13:05:30,487 (GMT+2) [5] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming RequestScopedTokenMessage (1.0.1) message:
    scope: http://tempuri.org/DataApi/retrieveTimeTable
    oauth_callback: x-oauthflow://callback/
    oauth_consumer_key: sampleconsumer
    oauth_nonce: 913320039
    oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
    oauth_signature: yfPMlcFo6/NgJltyCLc++RMyQCY=
    oauth_version: 1.0
    oauth_timestamp: 1337339130
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd need a callstack of the exception to know for sure.  Likely this exception is only an inner exception (ASP.NET has a habit of reporting inner exceptions rather than outer ones) and the outer exception would likely add the context we need as well.  Since you've already [enabled logging](http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs), you should be able to get all exception details from there, I hope.

If the `/` and `+` characters are not being encoded in the HTTP URL, that is a bug in the client that should be fixed.

Comment: I've added the log4net files- or at least, most of it. Unfortunately the whole thing is too big to post (in excess of 30000 characters). Hopefully this'll shed some light on things.

Comment: Ah, it seems we have found a solution. You were right, it was an encoding thing in the client. Basically, by using java.net.URLEncoder, the problem is solved- no more exceptions when sending the call from an android platform, even when oauth_token contains a '+' or '/'.